# Why is summary() produced from data.table output not printing to file?

Tags: r, data.table

I am having an error printing the ouput of a summary function to a file. I have a column "bin" with three factor levels and want to return 5 number summary for each level. The five number summary prints to the screen but won't write to file?  Error reports I have

> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: bin

Data:

```
       A       B          info          C bin
1:    10-60494 0.66392100 0.001833330   1 MAF0.01
2: rs148087467 0.35274000 0.000716240   1 MAF0.01
3: rs187110906 0.40586900 0.004488040   1 MAF0.01
4: rs192025213 0.00743299 0.000000000   1 MAF0.01
5: rs115033199 0.32829300 0.000614316   1 MAF0.01
6: rs183305313 0.51721200 0.002892520   1 MAF0.01

s <- df2[, print(summary(info)), by='bin']
print(s)
write.table(as.data.frame(s), 
quote=FALSE,file=paste(i,"sum_out.txt",sep=''))
```

Ouput:

```
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.0009998 0.0371300 0.2016000 0.2700000 0.4477000 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting zero rows is because the only thing you do in `j` is print the outcome of the `summary` command.

Considering the following example data:

```
set.seed(2018)
dt <- data.table(bin = rep(c('A','B'), 5), val = rnorm(10,3,1))
```

Now when you do (like in your question):

```
s <- dt[, print(summary(val)), by = bin]
```

the summary statistics are printed to the console but it results in an empty *data.table*:

> ```
> > s <- dt[, print(summary(val)), by = bin]
>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
>   2.389   2.577   2.936   3.547   4.735   5.099 
>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
>   1.450   2.735   3.271   2.991   3.637   3.863 
> > s
> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: bin
> ```

Removing the `print`-command doesn't help:

> ```
> > dt[, summary(val), by = bin]
>     bin    V1
>  1:   A 2.389
>  2:   A 2.577
>  3:   A 2.936
>  4:   A 3.547
>  5:   A 4.735
>  6:   A 5.099
>  7:   B 1.450
>  8:   B 2.735
>  9:   B 3.271
> 10:   B 2.991
> 11:   B 3.637
> 12:   B 3.863
> ```

because `summary` returns a table-object which is treated a vector by `data.table`.

Instead of using `print`, you should use `as.list` to get the elements of `summary` as columns in a *data.table*:

```
s <- dt[, as.list(summary(val)), by = bin]
```

now the summary statistics are included in the resulting *data.table*:

> ```
> > s
>    bin     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.
> 1:   A 2.389413 2.577016 2.935571 3.547351 4.735284 5.099471
> 2:   B 1.450122 2.735289 3.270881 2.991340 3.637056 3.863351
> ```

Because the summary statistics are stored in the non-empty *data.table* `s`, you can write `s` to a file with for example `fwrite` (the fast write function the`data.table`-package).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `sapply()` - here is an example using the iris data frame:

```
levels <- unique(iris$Species)
result <- data.frame(t(sapply(levels, function (x) summary(subset(iris, Species == levels[x])$Petal.Width))))

> result
  Min. X1st.Qu. Median  Mean X3rd.Qu. Max.
1  0.1      0.2    0.2 0.246      0.3  0.6
2  1.0      1.2    1.3 1.326      1.5  1.8
3  1.4      1.8    2.0 2.026      2.3  2.5
```